# Why won't this div appear?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to coding, and I've been designing a page, but I can't get one thing to work. In the following code, the div class: .third simply isn't appearing. I tried using overflow, etc, but it just isn't showing up as if it doesn't exist. Any help would be great.

```
 <head>
<style>
div{
    overflow: auto;
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }
h1, h2, h3, body{
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topp{
    margin-right: 500px;
    background-image: url('gamerbeta.jpg');
    background-color: fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    float: top;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
 }

.second{
     position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    background-color: #white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
}
.secondword{
    position:absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 435px;
    font-size: 50px;
 }
 .secondp{
    position:absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
 }
 .secondimage{
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 1230px;
 }
 .secondwordtwo{
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 1180px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
 }
 .arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;
    left: 900px;
 }
 .third{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px:
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
 }
```

```
<body>
<div class=topp></div>

<div class=second>
 <div class=secondword><h1>BETA</h1></div>
 <div class=secondp>EXCLUSIVE ACHIEVEMENT<br>FOR JOINING BETA</div>
 <div class=secondimage><img src="test.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class=secondwordtwo>Beta Tester</div>
 <div class=arrow><img src="arrow.png" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
 </div>

<div class=third>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I copies your code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1yysLps/) and it does show. Obviously you need to add some text to the `div`

Comment: I have added an answer as well and it tells something that everybody forgot to mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be a `;` not a `:` on `height`:

```
.third {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}
```

Comment: You sir, made lots of people looking into this problem look stupid including me haha

Comment: That was it! Thank you!! Can't believe I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so taking a quick look. It looks like your class third is at the very very bottom of things. Because it is outside of your second class, it is at the very bottom. What I did to find it was went inside the div and added just a little bit of text to find it.

like so

```
<div class=third>
Where is my div???
</div>
```

And i ended up finding the div all at the very bottom of the page. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeC answered, you have a typo, you have used `:` instead of `;`. This kind of mistakes are done by professionals also. To check whether you have any typo or any other common mistake, you should consider using the Browser Console. Every browser has its own console, which can be used by developers to validate their code.

Following are the links to some of the tutorials on different Browser Console:

[Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

[Mozilla FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

[Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/console/)

[Apple Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)

[Microsoft Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx)